# How to have quotes inside of a variable in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm writing code in visual studio, but I'm trying to put " within a variable. Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        sb.AppendLine("@echo off")
        Dim i As Integer
        Randomize()
        i = (Rnd() * 5) + 1
        If i < 2 Then
            sb.AppendLine("Start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "https://www.google.com"")
            ' I'm trying to put the line above with quotes in it. The quotes within the line like at ("%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe") must stay quotes for them to be recognized in my batch file
            sb.AppendLine("echo.")
            sb.AppendLine("echo.")
            sb.AppendLine("echo.")
            sb.AppendLine("echo WARNING!!! PROCEED WITH CAUTION")
            sb.AppendLine("ping 1.1.1.1 -w -n 1")
            sb.AppendLine("GoTo begin")
            GoTo Save
        ElseIf i >= 2 And i <= 5 Then
            Label2.Text = "2-4"
            Label3.Text = i
        Else
            Label2.Text = "5"
            Label3.Text = i
        End If
    Save:
        IO.File.WriteAllText("Xx_hi_xX.bat", sb.ToString())

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delimit the quotation marks by putting a backslash \ in front of them so your command becomes

```
sb.AppendLine("Start \"\" \"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\" \"https://www.google.com\"")
```

Alternatively, replace the quotation marks with chr(34) and append the strings with &

Comment: It says "character is not valid" when it hits the percent sign

Comment: OK try this instead: make the string and just add it to the rest of your stringbuilder `Dim sb As String
        sb = "Start " & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Chr(37) & "ProgramFiles" & Chr(37) & "\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe\" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & "https://www.google.com\" & Chr(34)`